# History of particular content items

Tags: views, nodes

I want to track the history of particular content items on particular date,
ex: i have saved the node of content on 9/4/2015 and also i have edited the same node on 9/9/15, so when i give the from date 9/4/15 to date 9/9/15 with filter condition field,it should show the all changes that has been done for that particular filter condition field on **From to To date mentioned**, I tried to create a view of content revisions but it's of no use because revisions are shown for all content items. How do I create a view of the revisions of a specific item?by giving filter condition From to To date.

Comment: can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module.

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's
>   "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of
>   node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked
>   per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation
>   moderates revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% certain I understand the question, but generally all you need to do to set up revision history is goto the edit screen for the content type, open the "Publishing options" tab at the bottom and check the "Create new revision" checkbox.

Note that you won't see any change to the UI until you save the node for the second time as that is when the first revertible revision is created. At that moment the "Revisions" tab will appear above the content.

Comment: i tried with this, i want to see the all node saved history of content type at once just like browsing history for ex

Comment: Ah, so you want to see all edits to all nodes of a certain content type on one page? Is that right? In that case you could create a view of content revisions , filter by content type, and optionally use node id as grouping field to bunch all revisions of the same node together